# How many table I need in database

Tags: database, database-design

In the interview, the interviewer asked me how many Foreign keys do the tables have in your database; I replied it depends on my requirements. His replied No. Also another challenge was on the number of tables used and that they should be reduced. I need to know what is the problem with my database design?
Thank you very much

Comment: What did they ask exactly? Otherwise this is not clear. PS It is very hard to make sense of your English.  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. (Same advice for non-fluent & fluent speakers.)

Comment: how many table and foreign keys created for a application . exactly asked me this questions.

Comment: So they just used those words & there was nothing else understood, like a particular database or a particular application?

Comment: asked about ecommerce system

Comment: Your answer `I replied it depends on my requirements` is 100% correct. You cant do more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question on the number of foreign keys is like asking how many hairs are on your head? The answer is "Why the hell would anyone ask that?". So my guess is the interviewer was just trying to say something and that something was incredibly stupid.
Also the question on the number of tables in a database is as silly as the previous one. There should be as many tables in the database as there are needed. No specific rules says there should be a lot or a little.

Answer (score 2):

When an interviewer asks silly questions please leave this place because your manager hasn't enough knowledge.
It's best for you don't work in these places.